# How to construct a SQL Query to find values that have changed over time

Tags: sql

I have a table

```
product_id | price | date
1            1       2018-10-01
2            1       2018-10-01
3            1       2018-10-01
4            1       2018-10-01
1            1       2018-11-01
2            1       2018-11-01
3            3       2018-11-01
4            2       2018-11-01
```

I'm having trouble writing a query that will give me only the records that
have changed price, ordered by product and date

```
product_id | price | date
3            1       2018-10-01
3            3       2018-11-01
4            1       2018-10-01
4            2       2018-11-01
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: If a product ever changes price, exactly what results do you want?   ***All*** the records for that product?  Just the records before and after a change?  Be ***specific***....

Answer (score 2):

You can just look for a product where there is a row in the database for that product with a different price:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price, p.date
FROM products p
JOIN products p1
ON p1.product_id = p.product_id AND p1.price != p.price
ORDER BY p.product_id, p.date
```

Output:

```
product_id  price   date
3           1       2018-10-01
3           3       2018-11-01
4           1       2018-10-01
4           2       2018-11-01
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0abaf66f02ee9e0548831b9dc9816d87)

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions for this purpose:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price, p.date
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             LAG(p.price) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.date) as prev_price,
             LEAD(p.price) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.date) as next_price
      FROM products p
     ) p
WHERE prev_price <> price OR next_price <> price
ORDER BY p.product_id, p.date;
```

I would usually want this information on a single row per price change.  The query for that is:

```
SELECT p.product_id, p.price, p.date, p.prev_price, p.prev_date
FROM (SELECT p.*,
             LAG(p.price) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.date) as prev_price,
             LAG(p.date) OVER (PARTITION BY p.product_id ORDER BY p.date) as prev_date
      FROM products p
     ) p
WHERE prev_price <> price
ORDER BY p.product_id, p.date
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just group by product_id and price

```
select product_id, price, min(date) as date
group by product_id,price
having count(date) > 1
order by 1,2
```